# Press return key "without" dismissing software keyboard - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

I'd like to create a TextField, where it's possible to quickly enter multiple String items into the **same** field, by typing in the item, then hitting *return* to add it.

I've already got the adding functionality, however I don't want to dismiss the keyboard each time an item is added to the list upon hitting return, as that's cumbersome for the users to tap the textfield each time in order to bring back the keyboard.

**I'm looking for a pure SwiftUI solution** if possible.

What I've got:

```
import SwiftUI

struct StackOverflowSubmissions: View {

   @State var item: String = ""
   var body: some View {

      TextField("Enter item...", text: $item, onCommit: {

         // Add item to CoreData database

      })
         .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
         .padding(5)
         .background(Color(.gray))
         .cornerRadius(10)
         .padding()
    }
}

struct StackOverflowSubmissions_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StackOverflowSubmissions()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing the textfield delegate methods?

Comment: I'm not too familiar as I've dived straight into SwiftUI without being familiar with delegate patterns etc, so it bites me in the ass at times like this! I've made a custom textfield view with UIViewRepresentable, but it was all quite a pain getting things to work honestly. Just hoping for a nice simple future-proof SwiftUI solution, if possible.

Comment: There is no pure `SwiftUI` solution but if you want I can provide a better solution using `UITextView` and `UIViewRepresentable` that is completely good for `SwiftUI`. Thank You

Comment: That would be amazing!

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @MikeMaus I haven't done iOS dev for a while now, but believe I did get this sorted. If you trawl through the code in my app you may find a solution

https://github.com/Chris-Filiatrault?tab=repositories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the `CustomTextField` that does not minimise the keyboard instead the next `CustomTextView` is focused. This process continues until the current `CustomTextField` is the last `CustomTextField`.

```
struct CustomTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String // String value of the TextView
    let placeholder: String // Placeholder Text
    let keyboardType: UIKeyboardType // Keypad layout type
    let tag: Int // Tag to recognise each specific TextView
    var commitHandler: (()->Void)? // Called when return key is pressed

    init(_ placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>, keyboardType: UIKeyboardType, tag: Int, onCommit: (()->Void)?) {
        self._text = text
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.tag = tag
        self.commitHandler = onCommit
        self.keyboardType = keyboardType
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        // Customise the TextField as you wish
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.keyboardType = self.keyboardType
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.025)
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.tertiaryLabel.cgColor
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .light)
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textField.text = text
        textField.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        textField.tag = tag
        textField.placeholder = placeholder

        // For left inner padding
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 15, height: 120))
        textField.leftView = paddingView
        textField.leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always

        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = self.text
        uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.init(rawValue: 70), for: .vertical)
        uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    }

    class Coordinator : NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

        var parent: CustomTextField

        init(_ uiTextView: CustomTextField) {
            self.parent = uiTextView
        }

        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

            if let value = textField.text as NSString? {
                let proposedValue = value.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
                parent.text = proposedValue as String
            }
            return true
        }

        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            if let nextTextField = textField.superview?.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
                nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            } else {
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
            return false
        }

        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            parent.commitHandler?()
        }
    }
}
```

Use `CustomTextView` in the `ContentView` like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var firstName: String = ""
    @State var lastName: String = ""
    @State var email: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("First Name Value: \(firstName)")
            CustomTextField("First Name", text: self.$firstName, keyboardType: .default, tag: 1, onCommit: nil).padding().frame(height: 70)


            Text("Last Name Value: \(lastName)")
            CustomTextField("Last Name", text: self.$lastName, keyboardType: .default, tag: 2, onCommit: {
                    print("Last Name is: \(self.lastName)")
                }).padding().frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 70, maxHeight: 70)


            Text("Email Value: \(email)")
            CustomTextField("Email", text: self.$email, keyboardType: .emailAddress, tag: 3, onCommit: {
                    print("Email is: \(self.email)")
                }).padding().frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 70, maxHeight: 70)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for writing all this up!
However what I"m after is a single textfield, where I can press return without the keyboard disappearing, while implementing my own addItem function, so the string is added to the CoreData database.

This looks great for sign in forms etc, however it's not quite what I was after.